# Does Hebrews 2:6 imply that man is a little lower than the angels?

Tags: word-study, 1-corinthians, hebrews

Hebrews 2:6 (NKJV)

> 6 But one testified in a certain place, saying:  “What is man that You are mindful of him,  Or the son of man that You take care of him?  7 You have made him a little **lower** (ἐλαττόωt) (to lesson in rank & influence) than the angels;  You have crowned him with glory and honor, a  And set him over the works of Your hands.

But Paul writes in

1 Corithians 6:3 (NKJV)

> 3 Do you not know that we  shall **judge** (κρίνω) (to condemn,punish & sentence) angels? How much more, things that pertain to this life?

I was wondering how to reconcile the 2 texts since the author in Hebrews seems to allude to the inferiority of man compared to angels, but Paul seems to exalt man above the angels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angels in Corinthians are the angels that are the servants of the devil, not the heavenly angels that the writer of Hebrews refers to.

John Chrysostom explains this in his homily on the latter passage:

> *Do you not know that we shall judge angels? How much more, things which pertain to this life?*
>
> Some say that here the priests are hinted at, but away with this. His
>   speech is about demons. For had he been speaking about corrupt
>   priests, he would have meant them above when he said, *the world is
>   judged in you* [v.2]: (for the Scripture is wont to call evil men also
>   The world:) and he would not have said the same thing twice, nor would
>   he, as if he was saying something of greater consequence, have put it
>   down afterwards. But he speaks concerning those angels about whom
>   Christ says, *Depart ye into the fire which is prepared for the devil
>   and his angels* [Matthew 25:41]. And Paul, *his angels fashion
>   themselves as ministers of righteousness* [2 Corinthians 11:15]. For
>   when the very incorporeal powers shall be found inferior to us who are
>   clothed with flesh, they shall suffer heavier punishment.
>
> [*Homily XVI on First Corinithians*](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/220116.htm)